# How can I create a shortcut to Shadeless?

Tags: rendering, scripting, materials, shortcut

I would like to create a shortcut to Shadeless.
Is it possible? or is scripting required for something like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an addon for you because I already created it to enable similar custom shortcuts (*Show Only Render* and *Show Edges*).

1. Copy the addon file
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jendabek/blender_misc/master/custom_shortcuts_enable.py
   to Blender\2.X\scripts\addons
2. Enable it in *User Preferences* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> > *Addons*, it is called *Custom Shortcuts Enable*.
3. Create a new shortcut in the *User Preferences* > *Input* > *Screen* section and insert the *screen.trigger_shadeless* as the operator name:

   [image]

   Set some key combination.

That shortcut should trigger shadeless on / off on the selected material.

Comment: Jan, I really appreciate it!